# Measure similar to Jaccard index but comparing more than two groups at a time

Tags: similarities, jaccard-similarity

I am interested in looking at the amount of sharing between several samples (each represented as a vector of character strings), and to do pairwise comparisions, I have been using Jaccard indices. Is there a similar metric, but to compare more than 2 samples at a time?

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "compare more than 2 samples at a time"

Comment: I would like to look at intersection/union or a similar statistic for comparing say 3 character vectors at a time.